# Scilab csvRead cannot found file

Tags: macos, csv, scilab

For some reason, I cannot read `csv` files in Scilab anymore, which weren't written by Scilab itself. First, I thought it might be wrong with my files (although I have previously read them), but I also tried `csv` files from the internet and still not possible. For example, I used the first `csv` file listed on this [website](https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/).

The error message I get is `csvRead: XXXX.csv does not exist.` One week ago, everything was working just fine with the same files. And I am using Scilab on Mac, in case that makes a difference.

Has anyone a clue how to solve this?

Comment: I think you are simply not giving the absolute path to your file. If you want to use a relative path, then check or change the current  working directory with cd("path") or use the File Navigator provided by Scilab to navigate to the correct path. If it does not work then you have likely a problem of rights. Did you recently upgrade to Catalina or else ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but  unfortunately that is not the case. As I said, I can open CSV files written by Scilab, but not others, and they are all in the same directory. With absolute path or not, only the scilab generated CSV files can be open. Really strange

Comment: Please give the URL to the CSV file that produces the error.

Comment: for example this one: https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv

Comment: I have no problem to read it. What is your Scilab version ?

Comment: Hi, it is 6.0.2. I tried to install the newest one, but it just doesn't install. Are you using Mac or Windows, if I may ask?

Comment: I use the 6.1.1 macOS version. If you want to use it, uninstall the Java JDK you currently have in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. However, I tested also with Scilab 6.0.2 macOS and I was able to read your file. What is your macOS version ?

Comment: my Mac Version is 10.15.7. I tested it in someoneelse's computer (macOS 11.4) and it works for him. But the weird thing is - it worked for me a few weeks ago. I haven't used Scilab since then and now when went back to work couldn't read the files anymore....

Comment: I have found out what was happening, the MacOS permissions were the problem. Added the bin/sh to the full permission list and now it works. That was probably why I could only read csv files which have been written by Scilab itself...

Comment: The permission problem is described and the fix you used was given there: https://www.utc.fr/~mottelet/scilab_for_macOS.html